# PowerPoint Shape Export Constant Image Dimensions

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I am trying to export a PPT Shape into an image file, however, PowerPoint is re-sizing the shape to the text length.

I know there is an Autosize feature in VBA, however I cannot get the msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape feature working in PowerPoint 2013.

My code is as follows

```
Sub RunMe()
    Dim MyShape As Shape
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim S(0 To 2) As String

    Set MyShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 100, 40)
    S(0) = "short text"
    S(1) = "Medium length text"
    S(2) = "Really Really Long and descriptive Text"
        For i = 0 To 2
            With MyShape
                '.TextFrame.AutoSize = PowerPoint.ppAutoSizeMixed
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = S(i)
                .Export "C:\temp\" & "\" & S(i) & ".png", ppShapeFormatPNG
            End With
        Next i
End Sub
```

As you will see, the generated image dimensions are different. Is there a way to create images of the same size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either adjust the text size to make sure it fits within the shape or adjust the shape to fit the text size.  My guess is that you'd want the former, so have a shot with this:

```
Sub RunMe()
    Dim MyShape As Shape
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim S(0 To 2) As String
    Dim sngOriginalSize As Single

    Set MyShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 100, 40)
    S(0) = "short text"
    S(1) = "Medium length text"
    S(2) = "Really Really Long and descriptive Text"
        For i = 0 To 2
            With MyShape
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = S(i)

                ' store original text size
                sngOriginalSize = .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size

                ' decrement font size until the text fits
                ' within the shape:
                Do While .TextFrame.TextRange.BoundHeight > MyShape.Height
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size - 1
                Loop

                .Export "C:\temp\" & "\" & S(i) & ".png", ppShapeFormatPNG

                ' reset the text to original size
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = sngOriginalSize
            End With
        Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have version 2003 installed on my current PC so the following is **NOT TESTED**.

According to some websites, `TextFrame2` is a new property from 2007 onwards.

You may try `msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape` on `TextFrame2` instead.

**EDIT :**

I tried this in my home PC with version 2010 and it looks okay. Give it a try.
Replace `TextFrame` in your code by `TextFrame2`